# How to convert a python/pygame file to an executable on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, pygame, executable

I need to convert my pygame game to an executable on Mac. I'm currently using python 3.6.5. I know there are modules like cx_freeze, py2app and pyinstaller out there but I couldn't find a clear and updated tutorial.

Can anyone explain how to use one of these modules to convert my game?